# Запретить скролл перелистывания изображений в галерее fancybox

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Есть такая галерея, которую пытаюсь реализовать с помощью [fancybox 2.1.х](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/).

Код, для примера:

```js
$('a').fancybox({
  width: 800,
  minWidth: 800,
  margin: 0,
  padding: 0,
  // height: 'auto',
  fitToView: false,
  autoWidth: false,
  autoSize: false,
  wrapCSS: 'gallery-fancy',
  helpers: {
    title: {
      type: 'inside',
      position: 'top'
    },
    overlay: {
      css: {
        'background': 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)'
      },
    }
  },
  tpl: {
    next: '<a title="Next" class="fancybox-nav fancybox-next" href="javascript:;"><span>›</span></a>',
    prev: '<a title="Previous" class="fancybox-nav fancybox-prev" href="javascript:;"><span>‹</span></a>'
  },
  beforeLoad: function() {
    this.title = "<span class='gallery__title-left'>" + (this.title ? this.title : '') + "</span>" + "<span class='gallery__title-right'>" + (this.index + 1) + ' из ' + this.group.length + "</span>";
  }
});
```

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul li {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.6/css/jquery.fancybox.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.6/js/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff&text=big-1#.png" rel="gr1" title="1 img">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff&text=prev-1" alt="">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff&text=big-2#.png" rel="gr1" title="1 img">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff&text=prev-2" alt="">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff&text=big-3#.png" rel="gr1" title="1 img">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff&text=prev-3" alt="">
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

При клике на превью картинки открывается картинка большего разрешения и есть возможность листать эти большие картинки (кликом по стрелочкам, либо при скролле мышкой).

**Вопрос:** Как запретить перелистывание изображений при скролле мышкой ( т.е. следующее\предыдущее изображение должно появляться только по клику на стрелочки)?

Comment: Вы не могли бы добавить в сниппет больше кода, необходимого для воспроизведения проблемы? Сейчас у вас fancybox не отрабатывает.

Comment: @Елена, в вашем сниппете сейчас переходит на https://stacksnippets.net/big-1.png просто

Comment: этот код для примера,

Comment: было бы удобнее, если бы в коде для примера наблюдалась проблема, которую необходимо решить

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для решения необходимо поставить флагу *mouseWheel* значение *false*

```js
$('a').fancybox({
  width: 800,
  minWidth: 800,
  margin: 0,
  padding: 0,
  // height: 'auto',
  fitToView: false,
  autoWidth: false,
  autoSize: false,
  mouseWheel: false, // ага, вот этот флаг
  wrapCSS: 'gallery-fancy',
  helpers: {
    title: {
      type: 'inside',
      position: 'top'
    },
    overlay: {
      css: {
        'background': 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)'
      },
    }
  },
  tpl: {
    next: '<a title="Next" class="fancybox-nav fancybox-next" href="javascript:;"><span>›</span></a>',
    prev: '<a title="Previous" class="fancybox-nav fancybox-prev" href="javascript:;"><span>‹</span></a>'
  },
  beforeLoad: function() {
    this.title = "<span class='gallery__title-left'>" + (this.title ? this.title : '') + "</span>" + "<span class='gallery__title-right'>" + (this.index + 1) + ' из ' + this.group.length + "</span>";
  }
});
```

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul li {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.6/css/jquery.fancybox.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.6/js/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff&text=big-1#.png" rel="gr1" title="1 img">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff&text=prev-1" alt="">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff&text=big-2#.png" rel="gr1" title="1 img">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff&text=prev-2" alt="">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff&text=big-3#.png" rel="gr1" title="1 img">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff&text=prev-3" alt="">
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

на момент марта 2021 года теперь нужно использовать параметр `wheel: false,`